# unwanted line on my chart using pine-script

Tags: pine-script

It's a pale blue line joining all the candle close prices.
The code for my moving average lines is like this:

```
study("trend EMAs", overlay=true)
plot(ema(close,180), linewidth=1, color=#1E8449)
plot(ema(close,365), linewidth=1, color=#CB4335)
plot(ema(close,10),  linewidth=1, color=#ECF0F1)
plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
plot(close)
```

It plots the close of each bar.